# Why would I use jbuilder instead of a hash?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, jbuilder

Say I was making a little app that would echo out whatever string you gave it in a little json object like this:

```
{
    message: "<Your string>"
}
```

What advantages is there is using Jbuilder for something like this versus simply converting a hash into json with `to_json`?

Comment: there is none. jbuilder is used to serialize objects

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why would I use jbuilder instead of a hash?

Jbuilder is a higher-level abstraction. As such, it offers myriad benefits over munging hashes inline.

A few that come to mind:

- It allows you to move your hash construction (and any associated logic) out of your controller and into its own template.
- You can construct partials, which can be shared across different templates.
- There are built-in mechanisms for fragment caching.
- The builder DSL is (arguably) easier to work with.

Jbuilder isn't the only option though, there's also [Rabl](https://github.com/nesquena/rabl) and [ActiveModel::Serializer](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers), amongst others.

You will not regret choosing one of them over manually munging hashes.